# Cannot access neo4j web interface

Tags: neo4j, remote-access

I have neo4j 2.1.1 running on a headless linux box (RHEL 6.4).  I verified that the server is running.  I verified that there's a listener on port 7474.  I verified that the line in conf/neo4j-server.properties is uncommented to allow access to the web interface from any machine.

`curl http://localhost:7474` returns a 503 error, as does browsing to the machine:7474

I'm sure I"m missing something pretty basic, and appreciate any help.  This worked previously, but the machine got restarted recently and now it doesn't work.  I vaguely remember doing something with iptables, but could not find the tutorial I used previously.

Output of curl:

```
 curl http://localhost:7474/webadmin
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 503 </title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 503</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /webadmin. Reason:
<pre>    Service Unavailable</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i>
</body>
</html>



>netstat -anp |grep 7474
tcp        0      0 :::7474                     :::*                        LISTEN      475/java

>service neo4j-service status
Neo4j Server is running at pid 475
```

Comment: Can you check the log files in data/log/* and data/graph.db/messages.log for any error messages? Perhaps try `curl http://localhost:7474/` first

Comment: curl http://localhost:7474/ has the same outcome. console.log has a java error caused  by jetty:
10:56:05.374 [main] WARN  o.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext - Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7e94c035{/browser,jar:file:/home/neo4j-community-2.1.1/system/lib/neo4j-browser-2.1.1.jar!/browser,null}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad temp directory: /tmp/JettyContext7389732742567105888
        at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.setTempDirectory(WebAppContext.java:1211) ~[jetty-webapp-9.0.5.v20130815.jar:9.0.5.v20130815]

Comment: More info:  I stopped and restarted the service, still no joy.  I also tried accessing the db via the REST interface, and got the same 503 error, service unavailable.

Comment: I checked, and /tmp is world read/writeable, so tht shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there was a huge file in /tmp, which filled the partition, blocking Jetty from creating a temp directory in /tmp.  When I deleted the file, everything worked perfectly.